# Setting an object origin in python does not work in Edit mode

Tags: python, scripting

I'm trying to set the object origin points to $(1,1,0)$ in *Edit Mode* using Python using the below snippet I got from somewhere. It works correctly in *Object Mode*, but it does not work in *Edit Mode*. What did I do wrong?

```
import bpy
from mathutils import Matrix, Vector
from random import randint
from bpy import context

ob = context.object
mw = ob.matrix_world 

ds=Vector((1,1,0))
print('ds',ds)
T = Matrix.Translation(-ds)
print('T',T)
# transform the origin
ob.data.transform(T)
#bpy.context.view_layer.update() 
# move back globally
print('mw @ ds',mw @ ds)
ob.matrix_world.translation = mw @ ds
```

Comment: This sounds like the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). "*Setting an object origin in python does not work in Edit mode*" It doesn't work without Python either. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: This is part of a spline addon i am trying to create that allows the user to do multiple operations in edit mode. One of the operations was to allow the user to select a control point and set that as origin without having to switch to object mode.

Comment: The obvious workaround is to automate exiting to *Object Mode* and entering back transparently

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos. Agreed. But is there any other solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### TLDR

By going to *Edit Mode* you created a copy of the mesh data (called BMesh). Then you change the original data, but when you switch back to *Object Mode*, that original data will be overridden back with the copy (kind of like a cloud save overriding a local save in a video game). So use `bmesh.transform` instead:

```py
import bpy, bmesh
from mathutils import Matrix, Vector
from random import randint
from bpy import context

ob = context.object
mw = ob.matrix_world 

ds=Vector((1,1,0))
T = Matrix.Translation(-ds)

# bmesh
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(ob.data)
bm.transform(T)
bmesh.update_edit_mesh(ob.data)

ob.matrix_world.translation = mw @ ds
```

### The ramblings of an old man

What is setting object origin? If we simplify the problem and disregard rotation and scaling, just considering location, every vertex has a location in regards to the origin. The origin is simply a $(0, 0, 0)$ point, the point where all axes meet:

[image]

An object's origin can be somewhere else than the world's origin - this is the case when the object has non-zero translation in `matrix_world`. The object's location describes the offset of object's origin to its parent origin.

So how do you move 0 on an axis? Well, you don't, not really. What Blender means by "moving origin" is that it moves the object, and therefore also the origin of that object. But that already has a name "translation" or "moving", so "moving origin" means simultaneously:

1. Moving the entire object, and so also its origin.
2. Moving the vertices in the opposite way, so that they stay in place relatively to the parent origin and world space.

The first part is trivial, just test this in edit mode:

```py
>>> C.object.location.z += 1
```

The second part has more nuance… You can just loop over all vertices and move them the other way:

```py
>>> import bmesh
>>> bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(C.object.data)
>>> for v in bm.verts:
...     v.co.z -= 1
...     
>>> bmesh.update_edit_mesh(C.object.data)
```

But if your object has rotation and scale, obviously the local space translation is not the same, so you can transform the translation to the local space:

```py
import bpy, bmesh
from bpy import context as C
from mathutils import Vector

ob = C.object
me = ob.data
ds = Vector((1, 1, 0))
mat = ob.matrix_world.copy()
mat.translation = 0, 0, 0
ds_local = mat.inverted() @ -ds

bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)
for v in bm.verts:
    v.co += ds_local

ob.location += ds

bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me)
```

Or just transform the coordinates to global space, translate, and transform back:

```py
import bpy, bmesh
from bpy import context as C
from mathutils import Vector

ob = C.object
me = ob.data
ds = Vector((1, 1, 0))

bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)
for v in bm.verts:
    v.co = ob.matrix_world @ v.co
ob.location += ds
M = ob.matrix_world.inverted()
for v in bm.verts:
    v.co = M @ (v.co - ds)
bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me)
```

### Why your code didn't work?

Your code didn't work, because when you enter *Edit Mode*, a copy of mesh data is create in a special form - BMesh. Once you go back to *Object Mode*, the mesh data is overridden with that BMesh data. So your transformed vertices coordinates get overridden.

Imagine that you save your Blender file, copy it to a pendrive, take that work home. At home you call to your workplace and ask a colleague to open your .blend file and move all vertices by x + 1 and y + 1 and save the file. You continue working on your file, return to your office, and move the file from your pendrive on the hard drive, and confirm to overwrite the existing file on disk - the work of your colleague is now lost.

You can fix your script by first returning to your office, then asking the colleague to transform vertices, and then you can go home again:

```py
import bpy
from mathutils import Matrix, Vector
from random import randint
from bpy import context

ob = context.object
mw = ob.matrix_world 

ds=Vector((1,1,0))
print('ds',ds)
T = Matrix.Translation(-ds)
print('T',T)

# return to office
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')

# ask the colleague
ob.data.transform(T)

# go back home
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')

print('mw @ ds',mw @ ds)
ob.matrix_world.translation = mw @ ds
```

Comment: Nicely explained. Thanks. I have a curve. So, I guess i cannot use BMESH? I did the same by moving the points/bezierpoints and that worked.

Comment: @RMK so it was useful after all to not end on the TLDR part… Glad it worked 